# Вывести строку строчными буквами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
stroka = input()
```

Вводные данные:

```
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе все буквы стали строчными (маленькими)?

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `lower`:

```
s = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
print(s.lower())
```

Результат:

> ```
> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
> ```

Comment: не ясно, зачем минус. `.casefold()` можно использовать, если вы строки в нижний регистр переводите для последующего сравнения без учёта регистра, см. [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/4279)